# How to deal with issue spam in Google Code?

Tags: google-code

I am receiving spam issues in my Google Code project's issue tracker ([example](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=2494))

Apparently [issues can't be deleted](https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1069).

What is the best way to:

- Mitigate the effect of this spam?
- Prevent such spam from happening in the future?
- While still letting new users report issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but maybe posting a comment here listing spammer names might help:

https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=30508